# Printing with browser's "Shrink to page width"

Tags: css, printing

Here's what's going on:
- My Firefox browser's "**Page Setup**" settings have the option "**Shrink to fit page width**" enabled (which I think is default).
- If I do a **Print Preview** and print, the **page comes out ok** (text sizes as specified in my print css in points).
- If I print the page with JavaScript using the **javascript:self.print()** (which doesn't show the print preview) the printed page's text comes out **very small**.

Is it possible that the JavaScript call bypasses the browser's print.css?

Thank you

Comment: I just solved the problem. In my content there was a DIV with a float:right.  Although in the print.css I set that div to display:none, the float:right forced it to the right side of the printed page making it much wider, thus shrinking the whole page to fit - texts included. I set the float to none and the problem's fixed.

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer, not a comment. And don't forget to accept your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(as pointed out, I'm posting the solution in the form of an answer, instead of a comment)

I just solved the problem. In my content there was a DIV with a float:right. Although in the print.css I set that div to display:none, the float:right forced it to the right side of the printed page making it much wider, thus shrinking the whole page to fit - texts included. I set the float to none and the problem's fixed.